# Spring AOP : Create a poincut for a method in class which extend abstract class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aspects

I have an abstract class which are implementing some basic interface.
(**attack method is not inherited from basic interface**)

```
public abstract class AbstractClass implements BasicInterface {

    public void attack(String attackerId, float attackerAttackSpeed) {
           ... // method body
    }
}
```

I have also an class which are extending abstract class.

```
@Service
public class A extends AbstractClass {

  // other methods...
}
```

Right now im trying to observe method **attack(String attackerId, float attackerSpeedAttack)**

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AspectJ{

    @After(value = "execution(* package.A.attack(attackerId, ..)) && args(attackerId)")
    public void broadcastAttackMessage(String attackerId) {
           ... //method body
    }
}
```

But unfortunately Intellij told me that **This advise advises to no methods**.
Also during starting the application i received error with a stack trace :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 name binding only allowed in target, this, and args pcds
```

What i'm doing wrong? Is there any way to observe method from super class? Do i miss something?